# I created a Project with Laravel / Vuetify and dont have a .env

Tags: laravel, database, vuetify.js

The question is actually already given in the title, I have created a project with Laravel and Vuetify, in the Vuetify installation I have specified that he should install the Essentials and also overwrite data in my folder.

Now the following problem: I do not want to create a new file for each article that I want to write, I would quite like to run through a database, but have no `.env` file where I could define the connection and that frustrates me because I'm sitting here like an owl without a clue.

How can I include a database in my project? Do I just create the `.env` file myself and the project already knows what to do with it?

I tried to define the connection in line 23 of `vite.config.js`, but my IDE only gave me errors.

Comment: *How* did you create your Laravel - Vue app? Did you use the Laravel Breeze development kit? Please tell and show the details of your set up?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an expected behaviour. Are you sure you didn't clone from git cause then it would make sense.

However, you should have an `.env.example` file, just copy and rename it to `.env` and you're good to go.